# Property missing from TypeScript object but visible when logging

Tags: typescript

I'm new to TypeScript and I've encountered an issue I can't wrap my head around.

I have a method which converts one object to another:

```js
static fromPreload(preloadPackage: PreloadPackage, context: Context): PackageDocument {
    context.log(`PreloadPackage:\n ${JSON.stringify(preloadPackage, null, '\t')}`)
    let document: PackageDocument = new PackageDocument()
    context.log(`PreloadPackage dimensions:\n ${JSON.stringify(preloadPackage.dimensions, null, '\t')}`)
    document.courier_packageId = preloadPackage.packageId
    document.dimensions = preloadPackage.dimensions
    document.weight = preloadPackage.weight
    context.log(`PreloadPackage weight: ${preloadPackage.weight}`)
    context.log(`PackageDocument weight: ${document.weight}`)
    context.log(`PackageDocument:\n ${JSON.stringify(document, null, '\t')}`)
    return document
}
```

When this conversion is done, weight is missing from the converted object. Here is the output from running this method:

```
PreloadPackage:
 {
    "packageId": "courierPackageId2",
    "weight:": 1000,
    "dimensions": {
            "length": 100,
            "width": 100,
            "height": 100
    }
}
PreloadPackage dimensions:
 {
    "length": 100,
    "width": 100,
    "height": 100
}
PreloadPackage weight: undefined
PackageDocument weight: undefined
PackageDocument:
 {
    "courier_packageId": "courierPackageId2",
    "dimensions": {
            "length": 100,
            "width": 100,
            "height": 100
    }
}
```

So, my method receives the correct data, and everything is present but the weight propert after I've remapped.

I have no clue why this is happening, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: does PreloadPackage and PackageDocument has weight property?

Comment: Yes, both have the weight property as a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you paid attention to the errors reported by Typescript, you would have seen

```
Property 'weight' does not exist on type 'PreloadPackage'. Did you mean 'weight:'?(2551)
```

Note the colon within the name, not after it.

Typos are normal. But ignoring the error messages from the Typescript compiler isn't. Please pay attention.

Comment: I don't get any errors from the compiler in vscode or when running the tsc command. Thanks for this, it was driving me crazy.

Comment: that's not possible. VSCode most definitely produces that exact error, as it uses the *same* Typescript language services as Typescript Playground as well as my IDE, Webstorm. And *of course* TSC produces it. Unless you turned off type checking in tsconfig or something. You need to figure that out first, otherwise why are you using Typescript?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code, it compiles with no errors. If I had gotten compile errors I would have noticed. I found the issue quickly when you pointed me there, it was my payload I sent when testing through Postman that was the issue.

Comment: ok, then you didn't do the minimal amount of debugging. I found this in seconds by pasting your code in TS Playground. It's an SO expectation that users do their own debugging before resorting to SO.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I know, I've been here for a long time. As you can see from my question, I did debug, but I didn't see it. I'm only human, no use to continue lecturing me. The question is resolved.